# Does double ‘each’ make ambiguity?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Each person has each car

If There are people A, B, C and car A, B, C:

It means people have car A or B or C car or people have car A and B and C?

> Everyone works every day

It means people works Mon., Thu., etc or a person works on the first day, and then the other person works on the other day?

Comment: It's meaningless.

Comment: @Hot Licks Sorry, but it’s very meaningful to me.

Comment: Then why are you asking what it means?

Comment: @Hot Lick Why is it meaningless?

Comment: @Hot Licks Good news, I complemented the question! Come and join us.

Comment: “Each person has each car” means That A has all 3 cars, and that B has all 3 cars and that C has all 3 cars.

Comment: "Each person has each car" sounds odd, maybe because it is hard to believe they all wake up in the morning and decide whether to drive the Mercedes, the BMW, or the VW... so 9 cars total. Doesn't make sense. Lets say instead there are 3 bridges, and "each person had to drive over each bridge" ... that sounds normal. The grammar is ok in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

- **Each person has each car**

Each person (All the people involved/Everyone) has each car (every available car).

- **Everyone works every day**

Everyone (All the people involved/ Each person) works every day (every single day/ each day).

Each doesn't create ambiguity here.

Comment: 'Each person has each car' sounds unidiomatic without licensing context. eg 'What forms of transport are available to the contestants when it is their turn to complete the 50-mile time trial?'